# Mouseenter in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wrote a graph in d3 that is updated when the mouse touches it (using mouseover), the data are update, however mouseover will continuosly update the graph if the mouse is still on the bar.

So I was looking at the jQuery mouseenter. Is there any possibility to implement mouseenter in d3?

Comment: You should be able to use jquery to attach a listener for mouseenter.

Comment: Have you see this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/8nApzax9p5E google group discussion, or this example code https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/4166283? Do either of those help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add mouseenter event through d3.

`d3.select(".class").on("mouseenter", function(){ // do stuff })`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think the difference between "mouseover" and "mouseenter" is that "mouseover" fires for the element itself and all of its child elements while "mouseenter" only fires for the element itself.</strike>

Mouseover: Fires when pointer is moved over the attached element or a child element. Moving the pointer to other child elements will trigger a new event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseover?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla_event_reference%2Fmouseover

Mouseenter: Fires when pointer is moved over the attached element. Child elements don't trigger the event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseenter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla_event_reference%2Fmouseenter

So if you want your own "mouseenter", you could do a check like `if (this === d3.event.target)`, followed by a `d3.event.stopPropagation()`, so you only get the elements the listener was assigned to. Hope this helps.